# Is it reasonable to use different Start Levels to manage the dependencies between OSGi bundles?

Tags: dependencies, osgi, bundle

My team are trying to develop a new system based on OSGi, and now we have more than 50 bundles and counting. The problem is, there is dependency between bundles. For example, when bundle A startup, it will register a service to OSGi, and when bundle B startup, it will use that service. Therefore I need bundle A startup earlier than bundle B. To make this happen, I set the start level of bundle A less than bundle B.

We tried to use ServiceTracker to avoid setting start levels, but when the services count growing up, it become difficult to manage and to understand the whole system.

However, I found this article on the internet: [OSGi and Start Levels](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/). I'm not sure with two sentences in it:

> - Start order within the start level is indeterminate!
> - On the whole, when working with start levels, never depend on start order. Think about start levels as a management issue, not a development time issue.

Does it mean that start level will not decide the start order? Then when should I use it?

Is it reasonable to use different Start Levels to manage the dependencies between OSGi bundles?

It is possible to make all the bundles being a dynamic module(use ServiceTracker to track all the services it use), but it takes more time and demand senior developers, and the system become difficult to debug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is similar to Bertrand: you should consider using a higher-level component-based abstraction for your solution: SCR, iPOJO, Blueprint, etc.

Using start levels to control dependencies is a little like using thread priorities in Java to fix race conditions.  Sure, you might make things work, sort of, for a while, but you'll go insane in the process--and you'll eventually lose anyway.

Start levels *are* useful.  The canonical example is if you need to display a splash screen while starting your OSGi-based GUI application by putting the code for it in a bundle.  Without start levels there's no way to ensure the splash screen would end up displayed when it's supposed to be, but using start levels this becomes trivial.

That said, I've used start levels to resolve dependency ordering bugs found in third-party bundles (e.g., Spring), though this didn't involve service ordering but assumptions about finding resources (with Spring, an XSD for the Spring Integration custom namespace).

Comment: My team has used start levels for similar issues. It's a great way to hunt down problems and it's a useful short-term solution if you don't have time to fix the underlying problem immediately.

Comment: +1 to rsteele's answer. Depending on start ordering introduces extreme fragility. Another use-case for start-levels though is optimisation. Your bundles should always *WORK* no matter what order they are started in... however sometimes a bundle may need to do more or less work depending on its start order. So you can use start levels to optimise performance of your app, just don't depend on them for actual functionality.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  I hadn't considered the efficiency issue, but it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 7):

Using start levels to manage dependencies between services is a bad idea - the Services Component Runtime (SCR) is a much better way of managing that, and if done right will take care of all the dependencies, startup order, restarting components when their required services are restarted, etc.

If you're using Maven, the Apache Felix SCR plugin ( http://felix.apache.org/site/scr-annotations.html ) makes it easy to create SCR-managed services using just a few Java annotations. Apache Sling's code ( http://sling.apache.org ) is full of examples using this.

Comment: We are not using Maven, and we ues equinox instead of felix. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Equinox should make no difference as far as SCR is concerned, and if you're not using Maven you can use Bnd directly (http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) - that's what the Maven plugins that I mentioned use under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

A good summary about the start level/dependency issue that explains why you have to avoid to define dependencies between your bundles with start levels.

http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Avoid_Start_Order_Dependencies